# How to export Large dataset (around 40k rows and 26columns), to be written in excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, dataset

We have a very large dataset (around 40k rows). I want to write to excel file.

I have already tried writing to excel file writing data cell by cell and it works.

The problem i face is , it takes lot of time to write to excel.

Is there any efficient way to do the same.

Comment: Which lib do you used for exporting?

Comment: If winforms you can run the task on another thread.

Comment: There are many more efficient ways to do it, but they depend on knowing what output you need and what code you already have.  For example if you just want the data in excel then CSV may be appropriate, or if you have formulas then you could write OOXML directly.  You could write it into a database and have excel query that instead.

Comment: If you don't care about formatting, I'd go with either writing a CSV file, or I'd use OleDb to write the spreadsheet. Both options are much faster than Interop and you don't need third party libraries. If you're not sure how to use OleDb I have some sample code you can tweak for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through every row/column, assign the full dataset to an array in memory - and then assign this array to a Range object of the same dimension. In VBA, this would look like:

```
Dim arr as Variant
arr = ... ' Your code to fill the array here
Set Workbook("YourWorkbook").Worksheets("Worksheetname"). _ 
    Range(1,1).Resize(40000, 20).Value = arr
```

Hope you can translate this to c#...

Answer (score 0):

If you write directly to excel, the idea from Albert works - but it will still be slow.
I would use a library like EPPLUS to write large amounts of data to excel - it is faster and more reliable.